# Get value from a parameter in URL in JSP

Tags: jsp, url-parameters

My URL is :  /something/page.jsp?viewall=1&CategoryID=1

I want to get `CategoryID` parameter value as follow.

```
<%
//String cat = "All";
String cat = request.getParameter("CategoryID").toString();
//String catID = catI.toString();
if(cat == "1")
{
  cat = "Books";
}
else
{
     cat = "something";
}
%>
```

I want to print value of `cat` as follow

```
<%= cat %>
```

But it is still printing `something` and according to code it must print `Books`

I don't know if there is any Data type problem or what . Please help me.

Comment: I predict that this question will be downvoted since "Scriptlets are strongly discouraged since over a decade."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a String value, so you need to use:

```
if (("1").equals(cat))
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how to accept an answer as being the correct one? All you have to do is click on the little check mark next to the answer! It's really quite useful for future viewers.

Comment: ya I know ... but it was saying do it 3 mins later then i forgot :P

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to check if that parameter is there in URL or not i.e if condition only if "CategoryID" is there in URl

Comment: if it's not there, cat will be null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11768/discussion-between-preet-jolly-chandigarh-and-jeremy-goodell)

Comment: Our chat conversation reminded me that if the CategoryID parameter is not specified on the url, my code as originally specified will result in a NullPointerException. I've gone ahead and edited my solution to prevent a NullPointerException.